# Merging two arrays by dynamically matching values using jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I am new to jolt and having tough time to get the desired output

Input JSON

```json
[
  {
    "getPatientDemographicDetailsOutput": [
      {
        "Message": "SUCCESS",
        "Results": [
          [
            {
              "APS_Age__c": "7 Years",
              "Id": "1234",
              "LastName": "LName0915-6",
              "APS_DOB__c": "2014-11-25",
              "Contacts__r": {
                "totalSize": 2,
                "records": [
                  {
                    "Alternate_Phone_1__c": "1458296321",
                    "Alternate_Phone_2__c": "(732) 318-3232",
                    "Correspondence_City__c": "Charlotte",
                    "Email_Address__c": "sohel@abc.com",
                    "Correspondence_State__c": "NC",
                    "State__c": "NC",
                    "Patient__c": "1234",
                    "Correspondence_Time_Zone__c": "EST",
                    "Correspondence_ZipCode_Name__c": "28222",
                    "Primary__c": true,
                    "Primary_Phone__c": "Mobile",
                    "Correspondence_Country__c": "USA",
                    "Country__c": "USA",
                    "Address_Line_2__c": "City",
                    "City__c": "Charlotte",
                    "Type__c": "Self",
                    "Zip_Code_Name__c": "28222",
                    "Address_Line_1__c": "Bangalore",
                    "Id": "11111",
                    "Correspond_Address_Line_1__c": "Bangalore",
                    "Correspond_Address_Line_2__c": "City",
                    "Mobile_Phone_for_Campaigns__c": "+1(732) 318-1232"
                  },
                  {
                    "Correspondence_City__c": "INTERNAL REVENUE SERVICE",
                    "Correspondence_State__c": "NY",
                    "Type__c": "Caregiver",
                    "Patient__c": "1234",
                    "Id": "22222",
                    "Correspond_Address_Line_1__c": "test address",
                    "Correspondence_Time_Zone__c": "EST",
                    "Correspondence_ZipCode_Name__c": "00501",
                    "Primary__c": false,
                    "Correspondence_Country__c": "USA"
                  }
                ],
                "done": true
              }
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              "Contact__c": "11111",
              "Text_Consent_Date__c": "2019-11-23",
              "Text_Messaging__c": "Yes",
              "Id": "54545454"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected Output

```json
[
    {
        "APS_Age__c": "7 Years",
        "Id": "1234",
        "LastName": "LName0915-6",
        "APS_DOB__c": "2014-11-25",
        "Alternate_Phone_1__c": "1458296321",
        "Alternate_Phone_2__c": "(732) 318-3232",
        "Correspondence_City__c": "Charlotte",
        "Correspond_Address_Line_1__c": "Bangalore",
        "Correspond_Address_Line_2__c": "City",
        "Mobile_Phone_for_Campaigns__c": "+1(732) 318-1232",
        "Primary__c": true,
        "Text_Consent_Date__c": "2019-11-23",
        "Text_Messaging__c": "Yes"
    }
]
```

Logic to transform last two fields Text_Consent_Date__c and Text_Messaging__c

- There are two arrays in "Results" in input JSON. I want to select Text_Consent_Date__c and Text_Messaging__c from second array if Primary__c = true(select only primary contact from primary contact list) and Id (from Contacts__r) matches with Contact__c(field in second json array)

Comment: The question has no relationship to MuleSoft products so the tag is no appropiate. Unless you are asking how to do the same operation with DataWeave.

Comment: There are more than one attributes in the JSON with keys such as `"id"`, `"Correspondence_City__c"`, `"Correspond_Address_Line_1__c"`, `"Primary__c"`. What's the logic to determine which one should be picked.

Answer (score 0):

This shift operation will help you generate the required json :

```
 [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "getPatientDemographicDetailsOutput": {
          "*": {
            "Results": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "*": "[&2].&",
                  "Contacts__r": {
                    "records": {
                      "*": {
                        "Alternate_Phone_1__c": "[&1].&",
                        "Alternate_Phone_2__c": "[&1].&",
                        "Correspondence_City__c": "[&1].&",
                        "Correspond_Address_Line_1__c": "[&1].&",
                        "Correspond_Address_Line_2__c": "[&1].&",
                        "Mobile_Phone_for_Campaigns__c": "[&1].&",
                        "Primary__c": "[&1].&"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "Text_Consent_Date__c": "[&1].&",
                  "Text_Messaging__c": "[&1].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```